# "Mathematica can't solve this" as a reason for closing a question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What should we do with questions which essentially boil down to one of the following:

- *Mathematica* can't Solve/Reduce/Integrate some expression
- *Mathematica* returns my input expression unevaluated
- *Mathematica* runs indefinitely when I evaluate my expression

I'm not talking about simple mistake cases questions with typos or which are obvious RTFM cases.

A few examples:

- [Minimize doesn't solve a problem with many symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73142/5478)
- [Reduce does not work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79045/5478)
- [How can I be sure Solve failed because there was no solution to be found?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82591/5478)

I'd say half of such questions are too localized and the other half are off-topic because only a WRI developer could answer.

But is that really the case? Usually I find it hard to decide. On the other hand I'm pretty sure no one who could answer one of them is likely to spot it in a list of old unanswered questions. Therefore, should I just make an edit to make it active in the hope that someone experienced in the topic will see it and answer?

Comment: You don't need to manually bump old, unanswered questions. If they are upvoted, then the system does it automatically from time to time (it will say "Modified [time] by Community ♦"). If not, then they will be automatically deleted after 1 year of no activity. So, if you like the question, upvote; otherwise, you can just ignore it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Right, I forgot about that. And what about those that got more than 0 upvotes but are in the same group? Maybe not the best example but: [35218](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35218/5478)

Comment: @OleksandrR. I know why I forgot, I know because it is not true :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/233085 so 2+ comments protect questions from being closed.

Comment: @OleksandrR. and the number of those protected 0 score unanswerd questions is 300! :) `isanswered:no closed:no hasaccepted:no answers:0 lastactive:..12m score:..0`

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that comments protect the questions from deletion. In that case we should probably look at them ourselves and decide what to do about them.

Comment: I agree that this is a difficult but important issue. I've thought about it in the past but was unable to come to any conclusion. Now that you've brought the issue up here, I'll give it more thought, but I'm skeptical that I'll experience satori, so don't hold your breath while waiting for my reply :-)

Comment: Perhaps, something along these lines should be added to the [common pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I will post here old topics I've faced that I didn't know what to do with.

**EDIT**: Or rather, I'm tempted to close them as too localized, simple mistake (in understanding functions/math) but I feel that I'm not familiar enough with the topic to do so.

Some of those topic are probably outside of scope of points made in the question.

Feel free to edit this list if anything is solved/closed, or if you found something:

#### Probably math problem:

- [Some questions about Integral Equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30337/5478)
- [How to increase range in Plot without exceeding maximum bounds?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42019/5478)
- [Is it possible to calculate with declarations only?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54905/5478)
- [Exponential function Integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41540/5478)

#### Performance tunning

#### Confusing fitting:

- [Fit a complicated function to a constant with NonlinearModelFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75979/5478)
- [FindFit for dimension reduction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26907/5478)
- [Non linear model fit mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41017/5478)
- [NonlinearModelFit with multiple parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38828/5478)

#### NDSolve, DSolve and friedns

- [Using NDSolve to solve a PDE with a Dirac Delta function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61176/5478)
- [Why does the assignment of values to coefficients make a difference to the completion time of DSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75848/5478)
- [DSolve cannot solve for certain branches of the solution help pls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41406/5478)
- [DSolve of the system of two equations with known constants](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76952/5478)
- [NDSolve gives wrong results for “stiff system”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50628/5478)
- [How do I set up conditions at infinity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58044/5478)
- [NDSolve: Couple ODE and PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46146/5478)

#### NSolve Solve and friends (like Reduce)

- [NSolve can not handle a PolyGamma equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73937/5478)
- [Solve is too slow with this system of equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85515/5478)
- [To solve an equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51847/5478)
- [Can't Solve a system of differential equations, Solve takes too long](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48226/5478)
- [Unable to Solve Two-Point Boundary Value Problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40262/5478)
- [Solve system of non commutative operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40989/5478)
- [How to determine why Solve[] failed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84144/5478)
- [Back Linear Substitution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42429/5478)
- [How do I find where the maximum is?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45255/5478)
- [Solving a single equation with multiple parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45875/5478)
- [Solving for variables that satisfy an equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51106/5478)
- [Symbolically solving a system of nonlinear equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58628/5478)

#### NIntegrate Integrate and friends

- [How can I verify double integral solution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78455/5478)
- [Speeding up Integrate and the numerical solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42945/5478)
- [“General” strategy to use NIntegrate for multidimension integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64861/5478)
- [MathLink wrapper for NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42829/5478)
- [Numerical integration with large exponents](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63103/5478)

#### Rest:

- [What does it mean when FindInstance returns unevaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80243/5478)
- [Interpreting a certain result of Minimize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48328/5478)
- [NMinimize ignores constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63727/5478)
- [plotting the stable and unstable manifolds of a difference equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65929/5478)
- [How to increase range in Plot without exceeding maximum bounds?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42019/5478)
- [Log of a Quaternion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43010/5478)
- [Smoothing a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37257/5478)
- [Unexpected result from InverseFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30813/5478)
- [eigenvalues and eigenvectors without Root answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42234/5478)
- [Any way of solving this system of nonlinear equations with non integer powers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78233/5478)
- [[Problem using RSolve]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77001/5478)
- [Shooting method for solving 3rd Oder ODE with RK method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43259/5478)
- [Strange “Collect[…]” behaviour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79418/5478)
- [Integro differential eq boundary difficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79975/5478)
- [How to add a positive definiteness of a unsymmetric matrix as a constraint to a Findminimum problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78860/5478)